# classpath mess when deploying war with org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server

Tags: jetty, classpath, web-deployment, embedded-jetty

I am using `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server` to start jetty and deploy war.
I have something like this:

```cs
class Runner {

    private static void run(String[] arg) {
        Server server = new Server();
        ...
        server.setHandler(webApp);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

I got a problem with `classpaths:` it seems that webApp's classpath contains (inherit) classpath of Runner class.

For example if I have spring service `com.my.MyClass1` in classpath of Runner (NOT in webApp classpath) and inside `wepApp` I run spring with scanning pacage "com.my" then spring will find and try to create bean `MyClass1`.

Is it correct behavior for servlet container (jetty)? Is it possible to configurate jetty to not have such behavior?

Comment: need to see more of the code to say where, but you are wiring things up incorrectly if you are not seeing classloader isolation for the webapp.

Comment: Please include more on your example code.  Especially around the creation of the `webApp` variable.